# How to inspect all .css/.scss classes on a website, using a browser inspect tool?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

How do I inspect all .css/.scss classes on a website, using a browser inspect tool? I'm trying to see all the properties listed in a .css for a specific website.
Specifically, all the styles for CSS class specified in the pull request fields in GitHub?

Using Chrome inspector I'm able to see CSS class properties of a few of the CSS classes, but some of them don't appear on the inspector.

The field references the class, but I  don't see it in the inspector.  For example, in the pull request body field I can't see any of the `js-`*** CSS class properties:

```
<textarea name="pull_request[body]" id="pull_request_body" placeholder="Leave a comment" aria-label="Comment body" class="form-control input-contrast comment-form-textarea js-comment-field js-paste-markdown js-task-list-field js-quick-submit js-size-to-fit js-suggester-field js-session-resumable js-saved-reply-shortcut-comment-field"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there isn't. From my experince, if the class start with `js-` it means that it meant for handling **js** selectors. Something like: `document.querySelector('js-paste-markdown').addEventsListener`...

And you can see it in their code. For example, the class `js-saved-reply-shortcut-comment-field`:

[image: screenshot of the code example]

See this tutorial: https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/ (Search for `js-*`)